# How to "palettetize" a 2D texture in modern OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader

## Problem

I am trying to write a simple program in C, using OpenGL, that would allow "drawing" a 2D C array (`int **`, 32-bit integers) according to a color palette.

For the moment (I am not there yet, far from it :) ) I'm learning how to send an array of 32-bits signed ints to the GPU and show it somehow.

I'm trying to do this in modern OpenGL.

My approach (bear with me as I just started learning these topics two days ago):

1. Geometry data consists of four vertices (`vertices`) for defining a rectangle based of two triangles (defining by picking the vertices using indices (`indices`)). The `vertices` data is also interleaved with 2D texture coordinates (for texture sampling in the shaders).
2. I do the generation and binding of VAO, VBO and EBO, to get the vertex data from RAM to VRAM.
3. Then, I create a 2D texture using `glTexImage2D()`, with internal format equal to `GL_R32I` as my C array is of type `int **`. I am not so sure about the `format` and `type` parameters, but I've set them to `GL_RED_INTEGER` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, respectively.
4. In the fragment shader I'm trying to "read" the original integers by doing something like `texture(texture1, TexCoord).r` but probably this isn't right... also tried to cast that red component to float: `(float) texture(texture1, TexCoord).r` but does not work either. Just to give you some reassurance that might code does somethings right, leaving only `FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f);` in the fragment shader does show that colour, meaning I get a rectangle filling up the window with that color. So only when I start fiddling with the texture I get either a black screen or cyan RGB: `(0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`.

Note: My C array is named `plane`, and right now it is filled up with  a left block of `0` values and a right block of `1`s.

Right now, I'd be happy if I could hard code an if-statement inside the fragment shader that colored the `0`s and `1`s from the 32-bit `plane` into any two other colors. Then I think I could proceed to include a 1D texture with the color palette... as done [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/creating-a-retro-style-palette-swapping-effect-in-opengl).

### Code

#### `pixel.h`

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H

/* 
  To make sure there will be no header conflicts, you can define
  GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE before the GLFW header to explicitly disable
  inclusion of the development environment header. This also allows
  the two headers to be included in any order. 
*/
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <plane.h>
#include <utils.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#endif
```

#### `pixel.c`

```
#include <pixel.h>

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"
"out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"   TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n"
"}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"uniform isampler2D texture1;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"   //FragColor = vec4(texture(texture1, TexCoord).r, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main(void)
{
  
  // Window width and height.
  const unsigned int width = 20;
  const unsigned int height = 10;
  
  // Before you can use most GLFW functions, the library must be initialized.
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    printf("Could not initialise GLFW library!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  /*
   * By default, the OpenGL context GLFW creates may have any version.
   * You can require a minimum OpenGL version by setting the
   * GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR and GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR hints
   * before creation. If the required minimum version is not supported
   * on the machine, context (and window) creation fails.
   */
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  
  // Create a GLFW window.
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "pixel example", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window)
  {
    printf("Window or OpenGL context creation failed!\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  // Before you can use the OpenGL API, you must have a current OpenGL context.
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  
  /* 
   * If you are using an extension loader library to access modern OpenGL
   * then this is when to initialize it, as the loader needs a current
   * context to load from. This example uses glad, but the same rule applies
   * to all such libraries.
   */
  gladLoadGL();
  
  /*
   * Set a framebuffer size callback to update the viewport when
   * the window size changes.
   */
  glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, fb);
  
  /*
   * 
   * Data to be drawn.
   * 
   */
  int **plane = NewPlane(width, height);
  PLANE(width, height, if (i < width / 2) plane[i][j] = 0; else plane[i][j] = 1;)
  //plane[width/2][height/2] = 1;
  //PLANE(width, height, printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, plane[i][j]);)
  printf("size of int: %ld bytes\n", sizeof(int));
  
  // build and compile our shader program
  // ------------------------------------
  // vertex shader
  unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  // check for shader compile errors
  int success;
  char infoLog[512];
  glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success)
  {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  // fragment shader
  unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  // check for shader compile errors
  glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success)
  {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
  printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  // link shaders
  unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
  // check for linking errors
  glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success) {
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    printf("ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED%s\n", infoLog);
  }
  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
  
  
  // float vertices[] = {
  //    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // top right
  //    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
  //   -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
  //   -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f  // top left 
  // };
  float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // texture coords
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
  };
  
  unsigned int indices[] = {
    // note that we start from 0!
    0, 1, 3, // first triangle
    1, 2, 3 // second triangle
  };
  
  unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  printf("VAO: %d\n", VAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  printf("VBO: %d\n", VBO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
  printf("EBO: %d\n", EBO);
  // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  
  // glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  // glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  // position attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  // texture coord attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  
  
  // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
  
  // remember: do NOT unbind the EBO while a VAO is active as the bound element buffer object IS stored in the VAO; keep the EBO bound.
  //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  
  // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
  // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
  glBindVertexArray(0); 
  
  // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
  //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
  
  unsigned int texture;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  if (plane) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, plane);
  }
  
  /*
   * 
   * Main loop
   * 
   */
  
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    
    // Check if Escape is pressed and signal to close the window.
    input(window);
    
    // The glClearColor function is a state-setting function
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    
    // The glClear is a state-using function in that it uses the
    // current state to retrieve the clearing color from.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // Rendering goes here.
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  
  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

#### `plane.h`

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PLANE(width, height, A) {int i,j,_ii,_jj;for(i=0,_ii=width;i<_ii;i++)for(j=0,_jj=height;j<_jj;j++){A};}

int **NewPlane(int, int);

#endif
```

#### `plane.c`

```
#include <plane.h>

int **NewPlane(int width,int height)
{
  int **a;
  int i,j;
  
  a = (int **)calloc((size_t)(width),sizeof(int *));
  if (a == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"NewPlane: error in memory allocation\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  a[0] = (int *)calloc((size_t)((width)*(height)),sizeof(int));
  if (a[0] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"NewPlane: error in memory allocation\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (i=1,j=width; i < j; i++)
    a[i] = a[i-1] + height;
  
  return a;
}
```

Comment: I can edit it and making it more specific by adding pieces of code of what I have been trying to do to make it less open-ended.

Comment: You still ask for off-site resources: *"Do you happen to know a good online resource that might discuss or illustrate such a use case?"*

Comment: Come on, don't be that kind of peer... The post now also shows code and asks for help on how to develop it towards the end goal. If it makes you happy I can remove the questions about external resources.

Comment: Problem is: What you ask for is basically a tutorial about using modern OpenGL. That's far too much to be explained in a answer here. If you already have shaders and everything setup, then a question about how to use a second texture to map integers to values might be on-topic, but converting an fixed-function OpenGL code to modern OpenGL is too much. Most of your code, including matrix stack and drawing with glBegin/glEnd needs to be converted to modern GL.

Comment: @BDL: My post's latest version does not include the word tutorial. The question is specific: how to include the 1D texture and use in a shader fragment.

Comment: And by the way, as a question implies, I can't know before hand if my code involves a lot of rewriting or not. But in my humble ignorance, the aspects of the code you are highlighting are actually tangential to my question. My question is about the creation of the two textures and the shader code to do the color remapping. But you choose to focus on _matrix stack and drawing with glBegin/glEnd_...

Comment: @BDL's point is that your code is using the deprecated fixed function pipeline, not modern OpenGL.

Comment: @rmagn0: I understand where you come from. But the code you have does not (easily) support that you apply shader. Imho, it makes more sense if you rewrite your code first with modern OpenGL/shaders and then ask with this code. In this case, the answers would just need to adjust your existing shader and show how to apply a pallet instead of rewriting your whole code.

Comment: okay, thanks I understand now. So you're saying, what I want to do, to be done in modern OpenGL, essentially, needs me learning to write code with shaders from the very beginning. I had the (seemingly wrong) expectation that the shader code would come only in the colour remapping itself. But from your comments I realize it's essentially everything that needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @rmagn0: Yes, essentially your whole code needs to be rewritten. There are (limited) ways how to use shader with fixed function code, but that doesn't support integer textures. The only way I see to achieve what you want is to use modern (OpenGL > 3.3 Core Profile) code which means using Vertex Buffers and Vertex Array Objects for rendering and exchange the current matrix stack code with a math library (e.g., glm).

Comment: @BDL: I think I have put enough effort translating my code to modern opengl, I hope the post can be reconsidered now.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened (though I can't cast any reopen votes).

Comment: This question is completely unambiguous. Are you actually looking for a lookup table? e.g.: `vec4 color = texelFetch(colorArray1d, texture(indexTexture2d, uv).r);`

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget The question was repeated: [From C matrix to texture in modern OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73463122/from-c-matrix-to-texture-in-modern-opengl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since integral textures cannot be interpolated, the minifying filter and magnification filter needs to be on of the "nearest" filters:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

`texture` is an overloaded function. If you lookup a `isampler2D` with `texture` the type of the return value is `ivec4`:

```c
uniform isampler2D texture1;

void main() 
{
    int value = texture(texture1, TexCoord).r;

    // [...]
}
```

Since the internal data type is `GL_R32I`, the returned value is in the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The format of the default framebuffer is a unsigned normalized floating point format. The data in the buffer represent the values in the range [0.0, 1.0]. Therefore, you need to scale the integral value (`maxValue` should be the highest value in the texture):

```c
FragColor = vec4(float(value) / maxValue, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

---

One way get colors form an integral texture is to create a 1-dimensional texture that is a table of colors and use the integral value from the texture to lookup a color in the table:

```c
uniform isampler2D indexTexture;
uniform sampler1D colorTable;

void main() 
{
    int index = texture(indexTexture, TexCoord).r;
    vec4 color = texelFetch(colorTable, index, 0);

    // [...]
}
```